# Hide both .php and .html extensions with .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, server

I'm trying to hide extensions from my website. I use both `.php` and `.html`  i have a `.htaccess` file that hides only html, I don't know how to make it hide `.php` as well .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#Removes .html extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.html\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I tried to copy and paste the code next to the one that i have and replace `.html` with `.php` but it didn't work it gave me an error with page not found.

What should I write to hide both `.php` and `.html` ?

EDIT: I know there are many questions about that, but i couldn't get it to work with the information that i've got from those.

Comment: That's the wrong approach in both ways. Redirecting old URLs to extensionless ones is a workaround. Fixing existing links in HTML should be the first step. And the second rewrite block should rather check for `-f` existence of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` and only then rewrite. (Can't have two opposing rules.)

Comment: What about just adding `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`?

Comment: @mario Do you mean , I should my html links to extensionless ones ?

Comment: @Krii I added it but nothing changes.

Comment: I have seen this work before `^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]`